# MySQL/PHP: return two columns as an associative array as key => value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I apologize if this might have been asked before, or if this isn't even possible, but here is what I am hoping to get from a particular table using MySQL.

Say, I have the following table:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| property    | value            |
+-------------+------------------+
| style       | unisex           |
| color       | blue             |
| type        | small            |
+-------------+------------------+
```

I would like to be able to fetch the two columns `property` and `value` as an associative array from `MySQL`, so the end result would be:

```
array(
    'style' => 'unisex',
    'color' => 'blue',
    'type'  => 'small',
);
```

Just to provide context  so people don't misinterpret what I'm asking:

I already know how I can do this using PHP once I have the result back from a generic `SQL` statement that would return each row's columns as `key => value` pairs. I was just wondering if it was possible to return one column's value as a key and the second value as the value to the key for each row from `MySQL` directly to continue with in `PHP`.

Comment: Can you please look into mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: You can certainly write code that will translate a result set like that.

Comment: I know how to write code in `PHP` to accomplish that once I have the result from the MySQL query. I was just wondering if it was possible to do it from SQL directly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no out of the box fetch mode that will give you an array indexed like that (how would it know which is the key? what if there's more than 2 columns?).

You can use [`PDO::FETCH_NUM`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to build a new array, using the first column as key and the second as value:

```
<?php
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT property, value FROM table");
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$rowFormatted = array_map(function ($el) {
    return [$el[0] => $el[1]];
}, $row);
var_dump($rowFormatted);
```

**Sidenote:** it looks like you're heading into an Entity-Attribute-Value antipattern. This *will* bring you problems along the road, so consider redesigning your schema. Take a look at this resources to learn more:

- https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html
- http://karwin.blogspot.cl/2009/05/eav-fail.html

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought I'd at least provide a MySQL only solution since that is what was asked for:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `property`, `value` FROM `table` WHERE 1');
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

`$results` will be formatted as you're expecting - an array with `property` as the key and `value` as the value.

Resource: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php