# MySQL sampling with JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have table `clients` with columns `id`, `name`, `company`.

And table `agreements` with columns `id`, `client_id`, `number`, `created_at`.

Relationship one to many.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.company,
    b.number,
    b.created_at
FROM clients a
    JOIN agreements b
        ON b.client_id = a.id
    WHERE a.id = '{$clientId}'
```

And I have result:

```
array(2) {
   [0]=>
       array(4) {
           ["name"]=>
           string(10) "Alton Wood"
           ["company"]=>
           string(10) "My company"
           ["number"]=>
           string(10) "5435635678"
           ["created_at"]=>
           string(10) "2018-08-11"
       }
   [1]=>
      array(4) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(10) "Alton Wood"
          ["company"]=>
          string(10) "My company"
          ["number"]=>
          string(10) "1234545546"
          ["created_at"]=>
          string(10) "2018-08-16"
    }
}
```

How can I change my query so that I get an output?

```
array(1) {
   [0]=>
       array(3) {
           ["name"]=>
           string(10) "Alton Wood"
           ["company"]=>
           string(10) "My company"
           ["agreements"]=>
               array(2) {
                   [0]=>
                       ["number"]=>
                       string(10) "5435635678"
                       ["created_at"]=>
                       string(10) "2018-08-11"
                   }
                   [1]=>
                       ["number"]=>
                       string(10) "1234545546"
                       ["created_at"]=>
                       string(10) "2018-08-16"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: MySql and other flavors of SQL return data tables, if you want to represent it in a nested fashion instead then you'd have project that within your application.

Comment: I think that it is necessary to use somehow `GROUP BY`, but I do not know how

Comment: That's a PHP/PDO related question.

Comment: You may have to do a subquery to fetch the `agreements` table based on a foreign key if you have one.

Comment: Your query should't work with the "," after the created_at

Comment: my query is working, I asked how to remake it to get what I described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this query since I don't have a sample data (it really help if you post it:), but something like this might work.

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.company,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('number', b.number, 'created_at', b.created_at)) AS agreements
FROM clients a
JOIN agreements b
ON b.client_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = '{$clientId}'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

EDIT:
If you want the answer as arrays you can use

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.company,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(b.number, b.created_at)) AS agreements
FROM clients a
JOIN agreements b
ON b.client_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = '{$clientId}'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

But in this case you will be missing the keys.

Hope it helps

Comment: It works. But you can do this to an array `contacts` instead json_object `contacts`?

Comment: contacts? (did you meant agreements?) .  
You can use: --
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(b.number, b.created_at)) AS agreements --
If that's what you were looking for but you will be missing the keys

Comment: This is not the effect I wanted to get. I want an array which I described after the words: "How can I change my query so that I get an output?" in my question. Without json, only arrays.

Comment: Don't believe there's an out of the box tool to get that exact output. MySQL works with arrays without keys or you can use the JSON format.
You can probably try to build it yourself. You can probably check this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815766/mysql-php-return-two-columns-as-an-associative-array-as-key-value-pairs